# Cant even run code in browser because localhost refused to connect

Tags: javascript

Use Vscode for the first time. Use ctrl + f5 to run code. It opens up a chrome window and get hit with a

This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What to do?

Comment: You need to be running your server (or use the file:// protocol), otherwise the connection will be refused since there is nothing accepting it

Comment: Please provide [mre] so we can check if the error lies with your code. If this isn't related to your code then it is probably off-topic for this site.

Comment: Please try to set the scene and rephrase your question. We're not in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not running a server correctly. But if you are, that probably means you have a problem in your configuration.

If you just want to run a document that is located on your computer, Chrome will run it just fine if you put the file path in your address bar.
(I had a problem just like this when I was just getting started with HTML, CSS, JS. It is also important to note, if you are also just starting out, that the file path will need to point to an HTML document, not a JS. JavaScript *normally* cannot be rendered on its own.)

Comment: (btw about the tags, this post should be tagged something other that js, its a server problem.)

Comment: Also, what os are you running?